# Rudin Exercise 5.10

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Problem 5.10 in Baby Rudin is as follows.

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are complex differentiable functions on $(0,1)$, $f(x)\to 0$, $g(x)\to 0$, $f'(x)\to A$, $g'(x)\to B$ as $x\to 0$, where $A$ and $B$ are complex numbers, $B\neq 0$. Prove that 
>   $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{A}{B}.$$
>   *Hint:*
>   $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\Big\{\frac{f(x)}{x}-A \Big\} \cdot \frac{x}{g(x)}+A\cdot \frac{x}{g(x)}.$$
>   Apply L'Hospital's theorem to the real and imaginary parts of $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ and $\frac{x}{g(x)}$

Following the hint and applying L'Hospital's gives us that $\frac{f(x)}{x}\to A$ and $\frac{x}{g(x)}\to \frac{1}{B}$ as $x\to 0$. Plugging these in to the equation in his hint solves the problem. My question just involves the equation in the hint. It seems to me that something much simpler would do the trick, e.g.
$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f(x)/x}{g(x)/x}.$$
What is the need for such a complicated expression? I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Probably a typo, but what you want is that $\frac x{g(x)}\to \frac1B$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli You're right. Fixed it.

Comment: Maybe the author has not yet proved for complex-valued functions that the limit of a quotient is the quotient of the limits, provided it is neither a $\left[\frac 00\right]$ nor a $\left[\frac\infty\infty\right]$.

Comment: The arithmetic properties of limits (including products and quotients) are proved much earlier in Rudin's text. For reference, these properties are contained in Theorem 4.4.

Comment: Perhaps. I was thinking it might have been the fact that $$\frac{f}{g}=\frac{\Re f\Re g+\Im f\Im g+(\Re g\Im f-\Re g\Im f)i}{\Im^2 g+\Re^2 g}$$ and so on.

Comment: The relevant part of theorem 4.4 is as follows: Suppose $f,g$ are complex functions on $E$ (a subset of a metric space) and $p$ is a limit point of $E$. If $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=A$ and $\lim_{x\to p}g(x)=B$, then $\lim_{x\to p}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{A}{B}$ (if $B\neq 0$).

Comment: See this question (which btw also contains the answer) : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2268151/72031